# QJSEngine won't evaluate js array correctly

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qjsengine, qt5.11

I have a file `settings.js` which includes an array with arrays of settings:

```
[
// [property, section, hex-address, Bytes to read/write, type, lsb, msb, options]

    ["AEC Control" , "AEC Control", 0x10300, 4, "bool", 0, 0],
    ["Shutter Mode", "Sensor Mode", 0x10104, 4, "bool", 0, 0],
    ["Nb ADC", "Sensor Mode", 0x10108, 4, "bool", 0, 0],
    ...
]
```

As you can see the file just contains the array value without assignment to a variable and without semicolon at the end.

The `settings.js` is put inside the `resources.qrc`:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/js">
        <file alias="CameraSettings">resources/settings.js</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

I read the `settings.js` with `QFile`. Here is the code to evaluate the javascript:

```
QFile cameraSettingsJsFile(":/js/CameraSettings");
if(!cameraSettingsJsFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
    throw std::exception("CameraSettingsProperties-file not valid!");
};

QJSEngine jsengine;
std::cout << "Output: '" << QTextStream(&cameraSettingsJsFile).readAll().toStdString() << "';" << std::endl;
QJSValue settingsArrayJSValue = jsengine.evaluate(QTextStream(&cameraSettingsJsFile).readAll());
```

Because of the *`Output`* line i know that the file is read correctly however `QJSEngine` won't evaluate the value correctly. Because `settingsArrayJSValue.isArray()` evaluates to **false** i called all `is...()` functions on `settingsArrayJSValue`. Only `settingsArrayJSValue.isUndefined()` evaluates to **true**.

I also tried this:

```
jsengine.evaluate("x=" + QTextStream(&cameraSettingsJsFile).readAll() + ";");
```

Then `settingsArrayJSValue.isObject()` evaluates to **true** (which is in a way expected when speaking of the js world) but i also get a `SyntaxError`: `Expected token 'numeric literal'`.

My final goal here is to parse the setttings array. Therefore i want to `JSON.stringify` the evaluated array and work with Qt `QJson` classes:

```
QJSValueList stringifyArguments;
stringifyArguments.append(settingsArrayJSValue);
QString evaluationResultString = jsengine
    .evaluate(QString("JSON.stringify"))
    .call(stringifyArguments)
    .toString();

QJsonArray jsonCameraSettingsArray = 
QJsonDocument::fromJson(evaluationResultString.toUtf8()).array();
```

#### Why does QJSEngine evaluates the valid array to `undefined`?

#### How can get QJSEngine to evaluate the array correctly so that i can process it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was this line:

```
std::cout << "Output: '" << QTextStream(&cameraSettingsJsFile).readAll().toStdString() << "';" << std::endl;
```

Because i read the file there, when trying to read from `cameraSettingsJsFile` a second time `QTextStream(&cameraSettingsJsFile).readAll()` will be an empty string because the pointer is moved to the end of the stream.

So QJSEngine works fine...